# Ошибка при запуске Apache Tomcat в Windows 10, (Непредвиденное появление: Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2"") как можно исправить?

Tags: java, tomcat

Скачал Connect2id server ( это готовая реализация OpenID connect), он работает с Apache Tomcat о существовании которого я узнал 40 минут назад. Попробовал запустить его через консоль согласно инструкциям, в cmd вылезла ошибка:

[image]

Делал всё вроде согласно инструкции в прилагаемом к серверу файле.

- Скачал и установил Java Development Kit.
- В файл startup.bat добавил JAVA_HOME.

[image]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все остальные вызовы `set` отличаются по синтаксису и выглядят так `set "ключ=значение"`, Ваш так: `set ключ="значение"`. Кроме этого, в пути есть пробелы, `Tomcat` плохо их понимает в этом случае. Попробуйте либо установить `Java` в каталог с именем без пробелов, либо использовать уловку, назвав в конфигурационном файле часть каталога так: `C:\Progra~1\Java\...` Ещё один способ - редактировать `conf\catalina.properties`, поскольку это классический файл свойств `Java` и пробелы понимает

Comment: Изменил set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2" на set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2", ошибка осталась.

Comment: Попробуйте либо установить Java в каталог с именем без пробелов, либо использовать уловку, назвав в конфигурационном файле часть каталога так: C:\Progra~1\Java\... Явно set не умеет работать с пробелами без  доп. усилий

Comment: Уловка "C:\Progra~1\J" не помогла, установил JDK, в C:\Java, сервер запустился, с ошибками или нет не знаю, но вроде всё работает, спасибо.

Comment: Вы указывали C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-12.0.2 ? Странно, должно было помочь.

Comment: hinotf, да, я указывал C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-12.0.2, но ошибка не пропала, однако после того как я переустановил Java в другой католог сервер тоже сразу не запустился, я думаю, что это связано с тем что файл при редактировании не сохранялся, хотя у меня стоит autosave и я юзал Ctrl+S, всё заработало после того как я закрыл файл с сохранением и открыл его снова.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема. Помог [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1024471). В итоге, прописал так:

```
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231"
```

Сервер запустился, но страница не открывалась со стандартным портом 8080.

В C:\Tomcat\conf изменил порт с 8080 на 80 в server.xml:

```
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        connectionTimeout="20000"
        redirectPort="8443" />
```

Всё заработало.